# Match all subdomains except one in mod_rewrite

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

Ok, so I'm doing a mod_rewrite, and I'm in a situation to where I need to match any subdomain except for one. It starts out looking like this.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+)\.example\.com$ [NC]
```

So that matches and captures a single subdomain, no periods. But let's say I don't want to match the submdomain named 'dog'. I tried to do this with a negative lookahead like so.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((?!dog)[^\.]+)\.example\.com$ [NC]
```

This works, for the most part. *dog.example.com* no longer matches, which is good. However, *doggies.example.com* also no longer matches. That is not good.

I was able to fix this by using a negative lookahead combined with a negative look-behind like so.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((?!dog)[^\.]+(?<!dog))\.example\.com$ [NC]
```

This works. It works perfectly, as far as I can tell. The thing is, I can't believe that is the best way to achieve this match. A lookahead *and* a look-behind? Really? What is the "correct" way to achieve an equivalent expression?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to use a negative lookahead, you need to anchor the expression to the dot:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((?!dog\.)[^.]+)\.example\.com$ [NC]
```

Otherwise anything that starts with `dog` wouldn’t be allowed.

The same applies to the negative lookbehind:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+(?<!^dog))\.example\.com$ [NC]
```

Anchoring it to the start of the string with `^` will ensure that something that just ends with `dog` like `catdog` will still be allowed.

Another solution similar to what Vinko Vrsalovic mentioned is to test what the first submatch holds:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %1 !^dog$
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify things a lot using the negation operator of RewriteCond, like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+)\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^dog\. [NC]
```

Comment: That's ok, but my problem is more complex than that since I have other conditions for multiple subdomains.

Comment: Well, explain that in your question. People do not usually read minds, you know?

Comment: By the way, you can have a single negation for all your conditions in a single rule RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !(^dog\.|^cat\.). But, then again, without knowing your complex situation is hard to tell if that'll help